# Can't change Bootstrap pagination color

Tags: html, css, pagination

I want to change the bootstrap pagination color but I can't in any way, It is blue no matter what I do. i want o change the .pagination li a.active to red and the .pagination li a to black. What have I done wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .pagination ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .pagination li {
    display: inline;
  }
  .pagination li a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .pagination li a.active {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
  .pagination li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li><a href="#">«</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">»</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> *emphasized text*</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could use !important or you could just add your external css file after the bootstrap css file to override bootstrap css

Answer (score 4):

You don't have any `<a>` tag with `active` class so you need to change two things

1. `.pagination li a.active` which should be changed to 
   `.pagination li.active a`
2. `.pagination li a:hover:not(.active)` should be changed to `.pagination li:hover:not(.active) a`.

see the working example below

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

.pagination ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pagination li {
  display: inline;
}

.pagination li a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination li.active a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.pagination li:hover:not(.active) a {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container text-center">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>*emphasized text*</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why but it worked only with a external css file

Answer (score 0):

Use "!important" after each overwritten css declaration!
Ex:

```
.pagination li {display: inline !important;}
```